# Can I control the colors of the title bars displayed by VcXsrv?

Tags: windows, xorg

I run VcXsrv in Windows to display X windows I start from WSL/bash.

Recently I've begun switching all my programs to dark mode. One of the things I have not been able to make dark is the title bar of X windows. As far as I understand it, it is VcXsrv that is in control of these title bars, not the program (in my case mainly lxterminal) or Windows.

In short: **I would like to be able to control the foreground and background colors of the VcXsrv title bars.**

I have not found out how to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to use the accent colour via Windows settings.

[image]

This isn't ideal as it means ALL your windows have this accent colour around them and in the title bar.

I would much rather vcsxrv windows followed the colour scheme but alas they don't and I can't find any way to fix this. I have noticed other applications not using vsxsrv do this too and it's more of a Windows problem I think.

So until the issue is clarified and brought to Microsoft's attention I don't think there will be any other way.

Comment: the accent color only affects windows that use the standard Windows Forms, or non-standard form apps that know how to read the accent color and apply it